# Sql Query trying use DECODE in Where ORACLE

Tags: oracle

This is my query

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT   cexp.expediente.num_expe "Num. Expediente",
                 cexp.expediente.cod_tipo_expe Tipo,
                 cexp.expediente.nif NIF, cexp.expediente.interesado "Razon Social",
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'NUMERO_FACTURA', cexp.md_valores.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Numero Factura",
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'IMPORTE_FACTURA', cexp.md_valores.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Importe bruto",
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'IMPORTE_NETO', cexp.md_valores.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Importe neto",
                 MAX (DECODE (a.descripcion,
                              'FECHA_PRESENTACION_FACTURA', cexp.md_valores.valor,
                              NULL
                             )
                     ) "Fecha recepcion"
            FROM cexp.md_propiedades a

                 RIGHT JOIN
                 (cexp.expediente RIGHT JOIN cexp.md_valores
                 ON cexp.expediente.num_expe = cexp.md_valores.num_expe)
                 ON (a.propiedad = md_valores.propiedad)
               AND (a.cod_tipo_expe = md_valores.cod_tipo_expe) 
           WHERE (cexp.expediente.cod_tipo_acto = '12EO' AND (cexp.expediente.cod_tipo_expe='CM11' OR cexp.expediente.cod_tipo_expe='FA11' OR cexp.expediente.cod_tipo_expe='CM08' OR cexp.expediente.cod_tipo_expe='FA09'))
        GROUP BY cexp.expediente.num_expe,
                 cexp.expediente.interesado,
                 cexp.expediente.nif,
                 cexp.expediente.cod_tipo_expe)
```

When i use this code, i haven't problem. This is the result:
[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEXKf.png)

But now i need include in the WHERE clause "Fecha recepcion" > '01/01/2016' AND "Fecha recepcion" < '06/06/2016'.

Can help me with this ?

Comment: Why can't you simply add the condition? what problem are you having?

Comment: @Aleksej if i try add this the error is this: QUERY VALIDATION FAILED: ORA-00904: "Fecha recepcion": Invalid identifier

Comment: For those trying to decipher the ask: the asker wants to filter the query based on the aliased result of the `MAX(DECODE(...))` functions.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierYanesDelgado: You should add the constraints in your outer query; don't try to add them to your inner one.

Comment: Yes @Cᴏʀʏ, Thx for this interpretation

Comment: If you need help with a query that doesn't work, you really should post that query.  Not just the one that does work. Otherwise, we have to guess what you did wrong.

Comment: @sstan this is the query ... The query works but now i need a new where clause with "Fecha Recepcion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to add it in the wrong place, it being calculated in the inner select, therefore - you need to wrap it with another select to be able to use it in the `WHERE` clause (at least with Oracle) :

```
SELECT * FROM (
..... Your Query Here
)
WHERE "Fecha recepcion" between '01/01/2016' and '06/06/2016'.
```

Al though this column doesn't seem like date at all, and to use date range functions this should be formatted as a date using `TO_DATE()` so:

```
WHERE "Fecha recepcion" between to_date('01/01/2016','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('06/06/2016','dd/mm/yyyy').
```

Comment: If i use the first solution works, but if i use the second solution the program say me "not a valid month" @sagi

Comment: Hah, not sure why, then use the first 1:) @FranciscoJavierYanesDelgado

Answer (score 0):

It only seems that you need to add your condition to external query, without relying on implicit conversions:

```
WHERE "Fecha recepcion" > to_date('01/01/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND "Fecha recepcion" < to_date('06/06/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: What is the datatype of your column? Because if it's a string, then '05/05/2017' would come between '01/01/2016' and '06/06/2016', whereas 5th May 2017 would not be between 1st Jan and 6th June 2016. Strings are not dates, even if they look like they are.

Comment: Are your columns varchar containing dates? If so, which format?

Comment: In db the columms are STRING and i dont touch this in my query

Comment: Then your predicate needs to be along the lines of `WHERE to_date("Fecha recepcion", '<format of the date in the column>' > to_date('01/01/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_date("Fecha recepcion", '<format of the date in the column>' < to_date('06/06/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')`, replacing `<format of the date in the column>` with the relevant format. To do it any other way means that you could well be returning incorrect data, as string comparisons are not the same as date comparisons. '13/04/2016' is after '12/05/2016' if you use string comparisons.